# How are strings rendered and evaluated

Tags: php, html, json, encoding

When `strip_tags(str)` is used the behaviour of any HTML tags in str is removed but you still see the string that was specified by str with whatever HTML tags it contained, the same happens with JSON in reverse where a string will cause an error if used by a JSON function unless some JSON encoding function is used on the HTML string. So, where is the magic actually happening? where is the rendering being done on these cute little HTML tags and JSON tags?

Comment: Can you clarify, or supply at least an example? I cannot make out what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When `strip_tags(str)` is used the behaviour of any HTML tags in str is removed

The HTML tags themselves are removed.

> a string will cause an error if used by a JSON function unless some JSON encoding function is used on the HTML string

JSON is JSON. HTML is HTML. Trying to treat HTML as JSON shouldn't be expected to work.

> So, where is the magic actually happening?

There is no "magic".

`strip_tags` is a function that removes blocks of text that match a certain pattern from a string.

`encode_json` is a function that works through a data structure and expresses it in JSON (adding `[` at the start of an array, commas after items in an array, etc).

You can see an implementation of a JSON serializer in JS in [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).